# Help with map C++

Tags: c++, maps

I have a map that links a size_t to a pair, of size_t and int

`std::map< size_type, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> > mapVals;`

essentially my understanding of this, is that maps work similar to stacks, and jst insert one after another, giving something similar to:

```
1 -> (2,2)
2 -> (4,7)
3 -> (8,5)
etc.
```

my question is, how do I obtain the value of the int. i.e. `2,7,5`. I want to use this value as the max size of a while loop.

Answer (score 4):

Maps are not similar to stacks; a stack maintains a first-in-last-out (FILO) strategy.  A map is something that maps a key to a value.

If you do something like:

```
typedef std::pair<size_t,unsigned_int> my_pair;

// Insert elements
my_map[3] = my_pair(2,2);
my_map[9] = my_pair(4,7);
my_map[7] = my_pair(8,5);
```

You can retrieve the second element of your pair as:

```
my_map[9].second  // evaluates to 7
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the int you can do one of two things

```
unsigned int myint = mymap[key].second;
```

where `key` is of type `size_t`. This works because using `[size_t]` on the map returns a `std::pair<size_t, unsigned int>` then calling  `.second` on this gets you the uint.

You could also use iterators

```
std::map<size_t, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> >::iterator itr = mymap.begin(); // say
unsigned int myint = itr->second.second;
```

Comment: It is not `second()` but `second`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want exactly

```
 for (std::map< size_type, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> >::iterator it = mapVals.begin(); it != mapVals.end() ; it++)
     cout << it->second.first << " " << it->second.second << endl;
```

- it->second : is the `Value` part of the map (in this case std::pair<size_t, unsigned int>)
- it->second.second : is the second part of the pair (unsigned int)

Comment: This is *NOT* working, as in this case, it->second is still a `std::pair`. Please, see my response.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Missed the first step. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef std::map< size_type, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> > mymapT;
mymapT mapVals;

... // fill the map

first = mapVals[1].second;
second = mapVals[2].second;
third = mapVals[3].second;

... // do something useful
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
typedef std::map< size_type, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> > myMap;
myMap mapVals;
// ... populate
myVals[1] = std::pair<size_t, unsigned int>(2,2);
// ...
for (myMap::const_iterator it = myVals.begin(); it != myVals.end(); ++it)
    unsigned int each_value = it->second.second;
```

The first `it->second` will give you the `std::pair <size_t, unsigned int>` element. The second `second` will give you the `unsigned int` contained in that pair.